# how to dispose an amchart line chart on each iteration of a data loop?

Tags: angular, es6-modules, amcharts4

I am using a for loop to iterate a data coming from a remote API.
i added

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.chart.dispose();
}
```

but it seems like it's not being called at all which end up my application crashing after about 25+ times of reloading a live chart using a remote backend API. what's the best solution for this to prevent my application from crashing ?

Comment: We really need to [see code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to guide you. What if the chart is being disposed and you're still having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by closing all the DB Queries from the remote backend API, then it stopped the crashing of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the steps at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-angular2/ these shows the instructions for adding the dispose method.

Comment: I know, you're referring to the `this.zone.runOutsideAngular` , it never worked for me